# How do I communicate between 2 robots?

Tags: ros, communication, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I am new to ROS, I don't know how to establish communication between 2 robots. I have launched 2 Husky robots in gazebo using namespace. The 2 robots must communicate with each other for data sharing, how do I do that? If data communication is not possible with Husky robots, then which robots should be used?
My main aim is to implement Fog Computing algorithms here and check how the robots respond to it. Here I am simulating in Gazebo but if I have actual robots, then they must also communicate with each other. Through communication, I mean they can send their data to one another, process it and return back.
I am using ROS-Indigo with Gazebo-2.2.2 on Ubuntu-14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236863/how-do-i-communicate-between-2-robots-?/) by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In simulation this is fairly simple. Just use the (namespaced) topics and services of both robots. As a single ROS Master is used, there are no restrictions and each robot can "see" all data of all other robots. Now, with real robots (each having their own ROS Master), things are a bit more complicated and no real standard solution exists.

It would perhaps help if you edit your question with some details on what you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0